# Greek Customs with Electronic Device

Tags: usa, customs-and-immigration, europe, local-customs, greece

I bought headphones in USA, for ~300$. Should I declare them (thus pay additional tax) in customs?

I haven't bought anything else and I am a Greek citizen.

Comment: Are you a Greek citizen or otherwise subject to the tax?

Comment: Which tax are you afraid of? The external tariff is defined at the EU level and thus exactly the same in Greece as elsewhere, VAT is 24%, which is not the highest in Europe and cannot reasonably called “super high” (lowest in the EU is now 17% in Luxembourg, most countries have at least 20% so just a few percentage points lower). In any case, USD 300 is within the €430 allowance so you would not even pay that.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[Greece has to apply EU rules in this matter](http://ec.europa.eu/taxation_customs/individuals/travelling/entering-eu_en). This means that if the total value of the goods you are importing is under €430 and you import them for personal use or as a gift, you don't have to pay any customs duties or VAT, as long as you are bringing them with you by air (rules for entry by road, e.g. from Turkey, or for things you order by post are different).

Comment: This also assumes that the OP is importing the headphones for personal use or as a gift.

Comment: @PeterGreen True, I added a note about that, thanks!